# mysqli importer file - disable foreign keys

Tags: mysql, mysqli

I am using this script to import a mysql file but I want to set foreign key checks to 0 when he will do the import.

https://github.com/davcs86/php-mysqlimporter/blob/master/php-mysqlimporter.php

Calling the file below with this function

```
include("Mysqlimporter.php");
$mysqlImport = new MySQLImporter($host, $username, $password);
$mysqlImport->doImport($source . "/var/dump.sql", $dbname, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
    //import data
    SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: thanks, I know that part, only thing I am struggling with is to incorporate that with the script in the link. Would you know?

Comment: u mean like this `mysql_query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');` !!.?

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` API.  Do use whatever in MySQLImporter lets you get at commands.  The `SET` must be done from the same connection.